# Serializing/Deserializing Type properties in Json.net (9.x)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an object like

```
public MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

I use serialization settings

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
};
```

which serializes to

```
{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "type": "SomeNamespace.SomeType, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
}
```

but then fails to deserialize, with error

> System.ArgumentException
>
> Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Type.

Is there an easy fix for Json.Net version 9.0.x?

Comment: can you please add a line of code which converts your object into JSON?

Comment: Why do you need Type to be serialized

Comment: the simple problem is that the serializer changes the Type to a string, but its not able to deserialize that via the defaultConverter.  I've used this link in the past to help me with very similar situations. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: Using Json.Net version 11.0.2, I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm using 9.0.1 and need to

Comment: @HiramKatz, I changed my version to 9.0.1, Still can not reproduce. Working like it is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

I ran following code and it works fine with Newtonsoft 9.0.1

```
private void TestJson()
{
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
    };

    var myObj = new MyObject
    {
        Type = typeof(string)
    };

    var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, jsonSettings);
    var newObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(serialize, jsonSettings);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

DLL Information:

[image]